# Launch Dash App from Jupyter Notebook using wget?

Tags: dataframe, jupyter-notebook, wget, plotly-dash, dashboard

What i have done is downloaded a already preset skeleton for my dash app using a `!wget` function in Jupyter Notebook, I was wondering how could i launch the app?
Is there something similar to this line of code i could use `python3 spacex_dash_app.py`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `!` symbol passes your commands to the underlying shell running Jupyter.

Similar to prefixing `wget` with `!`, you can run `!python3 spacex_dash_app.py`, after making sure that `spacex_dash_app.py` is in the same working directory as your Jupyter notebook.

Comment: For the benefit of others seeing `!python` as a suggestion to run in a notebook: in general, you'll get more full-featured support replacing `!python` with `%run` line magic inside a Jupyter notebook, see [here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-run). In this case, I'd probably try both though. It depends on how the `spacex_dash_app.py` is set to send output.